# Eliminate 0 Values From Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, polygon, arcgis-10.2

Arcgis 10.2

I currently have a raster file that I want to turn into a set of polygons. This will help me to create specific buffers around certain points. The extent of my values are 0, and 1. When I change from raster into polygon, I end up with polygons for both 0 AND 1. I only want polygons for pixels with value 1. If I have polygons for values of 0, I end up capturing a bunch of empty space that it totally not necessary to the project.

Here is an image of what I am working on (white = 1, black = 0):

[image]

Comment: Just reclassify the grid so that 0 is NoData

Comment: Or just extract the 1 using geoprocessing tool 'extract by attributes' http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000029000000.htm, unless of course you're saying you don't want islands of 0 inside your 1 in which case I would use the geoprocessing tool 'feature to polygon' http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003n000000 to fill the holes before using polygon to raster.

Comment: I used "Extract by Attributes" the Where formula was "Value = 1." This did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

you can use raster calculator to set your 0 values to NoData. Con(condition, value if true, value if false) will set the false value to Nodata if it is left blank.

in your case, you could use

```
Con(raster== 1, 1)
```

a more generic code would be

```
Con(raster!=0, raster)
```

when you convert to polygon, NoData pixels will be ignored.

Note that you can make something equivalent to the vector buffer using "[expand](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000036000000.htm)" on your raster.

Comment: [SetNull](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Set_Null/009z00000007000000/) is the ideal tool to use.